# dotnet 6 fails to run after build

Tags: macos, .net-6.0

After installing Visual Studio 2022 for Mac Preview dotnet was upgraded to 6.0.100.

```
% dotnet --version
6.0.100
```

However, when setting up a project it does not run after building complaining that no runtimeconfig.json is present.

```
% dotnet new console 
The template "Console App" was created successfully.

% dotnet build 
...
Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

% ./bin/Debug/net6.0/dotnet6-test 
A fatal error was encountered. The library 'libhostpolicy.dylib' required to execute the application was not found in '/usr/local/share/dotnet'.
Failed to run as a self-contained app.
  - The application was run as a self-contained app because '/Users/iigorr/dev/dotnet6-test/bin/Debug/net6.0/dotnet6-test.runtimeconfig.json' was not found.
  - If this should be a framework-dependent app, add the '/Users/iigorr/dev/dotnet6-test/bin/Debug/net6.0/dotnet6-test.runtimeconfig.json' file and specify the appropriate framework.
```

It does work if I explicitly build it as self-contained with the runtime identifier. (`-r osx.11.0-x64 --self-contained`)

Why can't I just run it? Do I have to include a runtimeconfig.json in the project?

Edit:

```
% dotnet --list-sdks
3.1.101 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
3.1.200 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
3.1.415 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
6.0.100 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]

% dotnet --list-runtimes
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.1 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.2 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.21 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.15 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.16 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.1 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.2 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.21 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

Comment: You *can* just run it. I've been working with .NET 6 on a Mac since Preview 1. Post enough information to reproduce the error. Doing what you posted I got `Hello Wordl!`

Comment: `dotnet was upgraded to 6.0.100.` from what? 6.0.100 is the RTM version of .NET 6. Anything before that were preview versions. Installing .NET 6 won't remove .NET 5 or .NET Core 3.1. Please post the output of `dotnet --list-sdks` and `dotnet --list-runtimes`. Perhaps you have leftover preview runtimes that need to be removed

Comment: Running `dotnet build` *does* emit a `*.runtimeconfig.json` file in the build folder. The files in the build folder aren't the final executable. The runtime needs that file to tell it how to execute `dotnet6-test`. If that file is missing, something's wrong. To produce the final executable  you need to run `dotnet publish`. That's the step where you can specify that a standalone or single-file executable should be produced

Comment: The steps above are exactly what i am doing: new, build, run => error
I have added the output of `--list-sdks` and `--list-runtimes` in the question. in my case the `*.runtimeconfig.json` is not emitted. Seems to be a problem with my setup.

Comment: completely wiping out `/usr/local/share/dotnet` and reinstalling did not help either.

Comment: Reinstall *how*? Did you install the .NET 6 SDK or VS 2022 ? Why not use the RTM version of VS 2022? Don't try things at random, especially not deleting or even reinstalling stuff without understanding what's going on. This *causes* problems instead of fixing them

Comment: To uninstall .NET use the [.NET Uninstall tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/uninstall-tool?tabs=windows). Remove VS 2022 before you start. After that, install the .NET 6 SDK only and try creating a console application again. Install the RTM version of VS 2022, not the preview.

Comment: Reinstalled via official .net sdk installer for mac https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/6.0. 

I am not trying stuff at random. I tried reinstalling dotnet itself. I did use dotnet-core-uninstall. It did not help either, as it also only removes skds/rutimes... dropping the `/usr/local/share/dotnet` was the next step. didn't help either. so there must be something else that influences how `dotnet build` works.

I don't want to use VS 22. I removed it right away. I only tried out the preview and decided that it's not better (yet?) then the previous one.

Comment: BTW: there is no VS 22 RTM for mac yet, only preview.

Comment: I seldom use VS 2022 too. I use Rider almost exclusively and only open up VS 2022 for some very limited Blazor debugging - that's why I keep forgetting there's no RTM yet. Even if there was, it's missing a *lot* of features. Performance is better than 2019 but nowhere close to Rider. You don't need VS 2022 to work with .NET Core